# Validating Output From a Clustering Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, data-mining, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

**Is there an objective way to validate the output of a clustering algorithm?**

I'm using scikit-learn's affinity propagation clustering against a dataset composed of objects with many attributes. The difference matrix supplied to the clustering algorithm is composed of the weighted difference of these attributes. I'm looking for a way to objectively validate tweaks in the distance weightings as reflected in the resulting clusters. The dataset is large and has enough attributes that manual examination of small examples is not a reasonable way to verify the produced clusters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**:

Give the clusters to a domain expert, and have him analyze if the structure the algorithm found is *sensible*. Not so much if it is new, but if it is sensible.

... and  **No**:

There is not *automatic* evaluation available that is *fair*. In the sense that it takes the objective of unsupervised clustering into account: *knowledge discovery* aka: learn something new about your data.

There are two common ways of evaluating clusterings automatically:

- internal cohesion. I.e. there is some particular property such as in-cluser variance compared to between-cluster variance to minimize. The problem is that it's usually fairly trivial to cheat. I.e. to construct a trivial solution that scores really well. So this method *must* not be used to compare methods based on different assumptions. You can't even fairly compare different types of linkage for hiearchical clustering.
- external evaluation. You use a labeled data set, and score algorithms by how well they *rediscover* existing knowledge. Sometimes this works quite well, so it is an accepted state of the art for evaluation. Yet, any *supervised* or *semi-supervised* method will of course score much better on this. As such, it is A) biased *towards* supervised methods, and B) actually going completely against the *knowledge discovery* idea of finding something you did *not yet* know.

If you really mean to use clustering - i.e. learn something about your data - you will at some point have to *inspect* the clusters, preferrably by a completely independent method such as a domain expert. If he can tell you that e.g. the user group identified by the clustering is a *non-trivial* group *not yet* investigated closely, then you are a winner.

However, most people want to have a "one click" (and one-score) evaluation, unfortunately.

Oh, and "clustering" is *not* really a machine learning task. There actually is no learning involved. To the machine learning community, it is the ugly duckling that nobody cares about.

Comment: This is what I feared. I've been actively applying a form of variance minimization. Should I remove the machine learning tag? I presumed it was tangentially related enough to draw the right crowd.

Comment: The tag won't hurt. Variance minimization (as performed by k-means) is a good example for the kind of bias: more clusters (larger k) will always reduce variance, but the result won't necessarily be better.

Comment: Excellent quote, "Oh, and 'clustering' is not really a machine learning task. There actually is no learning involved. To the machine learning community, it is the ugly duckling that nobody cares about". Is there a swan in the end? Clustering is a highly (lowly) underspecified problem, yet at the same time a very natural problem of cognition, and an important one. Its underspecified nature has led to way too many publications on clustering, and a flood of horribly concocted proofs of superiority.

Comment: For clustering to make sense for an application, you first need to think about the specifications. Most algorithms have some more or less explicit specifications, and people care much too little about them. Say k-means. It has the key assumptions that A) the mean is a sensible representative of the cluster and that B) variance must be minimized. If either doesn't make sense for a particular job, don't use k-means. (And frankly, quite often the mean is not sensible ...)

Comment: The beauty of clustering however is exactly that it IS underspecified. Because you want to some extend discover the appropriate specifications. But one has to live with having to try dozens of clustering algorithms until you find one that actually helps you in your particular problem. There is no one-size-fits-all.

Comment: @micans, "way too many publications on clustering" and too few examples ? Could you point to some example datasets online with good / bad clusterings with different methods ? Pictures would be nice too.

Comment: Pictures only work for 2D toy examples. You can't get good pictures for real 27d data. Good is whatever is useful to the user.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to **evaluate the clustering quality by computing a stability metric** on subfolds, a bit like cross validation for supervised models:

- Split the dataset in 3 folds A, B and C. Compute two clustering with you algorithm on A+B and A+C. Compute the Adjusted Rand Index or Adjusted Mutual Information of the 2 labelings on their intersection A and consider this value as an estimate of the stability score of the algorithm.
- Rinse-repeat by shuffling the data and splitting it into 3 other folds A', B' and C' and recompute a stability score.
- Average the stability scores over 5 or 10 runs to have a rough estimate of the standard error of the stability score.

As you can guess this is very computer intensive evaluation method.

It is still an open research area to know whether or not this Stability-based evaluation of clustering algorithms is really useful in practice and to identify when it can fail to produce a valid criterion for model selection. Please refer to [Clustering Stability: An Overview](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1075) by Ulrike von Luxburg and references therein for an overview of the state of the art on those matters.

Note: it is important to use Adjusted for Chance metrics such as ARI or AMI if you want to use this strategy to select the best value of k in k-means for instance. Non adjusted metrics such as NMI and V-measure will tend to favor models with higher k arbitrarily.